# Find table value between range of column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table name `tblRate` in that two columns are their `TotalDays` and `Rate` 
values in table e.g

```
TotalDays   |  Rates  
20          |  3.5   
30          |  4.5  
40          |  5.5
```

I want to write query that will return rate if I provide value of total days i.e if i provide values as 35 then it needs to be return the value of 4.5 that means 4.5 is come in between the `30 to 40 range.`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something like: `SELECT Rate from tblRate WHERE TotalDays >= 30 AND TotalDays <=40` would work. But show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(rate) as rate
from tblRate
where TotalDays <= ?
```

Where `?` !is your value.

This will work if `rates` increases with `TotalDays`, which it seems to do.

Comment: `select Top 1 rate from tblRate where TotalDays <= ? ` this is the exact i want it works with the help of your query.

Comment: @Milind yes, you could rewrite it as a "top" query, but you should add an order by to make sure you get the correct result:  `select top 1 rate from tblRate where TotalDays <= ? order by rate desc`

Answer (score 4):

If I got right:

```
select * from rates where totaldays = (@v / 10)*10
```

Or:

```
select top 1 * from rates where totaldays <= @v order by totaldays desc
```

Comment: your query is working fine till I try for the values less than last column of `TotalDays` not working if i entered the value greater 50 then still at that time i want to return value of 40

Comment: I had just enter the value 20-30-40 just for sample it may vary dynamically means 100 to 250 and 251 to 460 random i want that value from range